# Get input number value and loop to display text field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, loops

I'm trying to create a form on a HTML/PHP page that get a given value in an input type number field, and display dynamically in the same page new input type text fields depending on the value of the previous number field.

So in my form I have this :

```
<label for="number">Number of servers</label>
<input type="number" id="number" name="number" min="1" max="32" onkeydown="javascript: return event.keyCode == 69 ? false : true" placeholder="2" required tabindex="6">
```

When a user type i.e. 4, I would like that 4 new text field are displayed below.
So I'm expecting to use a decremented DO...WHILE loop but I have no clue on how to do it.

- Best way to check change (onchange, onkeyup, onkeydown, ...) ?
- How to properly display new input text field (javascript, jquery, ...) ?

Target is to have at the end something like this :

```
<input type="text" id="server_name_1" name="server_name_1" maxlength="8" autocomplete="off" required tabindex="7"> 
<input type="text" id="server_name_2" name="server_name_2" maxlength="8" autocomplete="off" required tabindex="8"> 
<input type="text" id="server_name_3" name="server_name_3" maxlength="8" autocomplete="off" required tabindex="9"> 
<input type="text" id="server_name_4" name="server_name_4" maxlength="8" autocomplete="off" required tabindex="10">
```

Comment: show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Start of by getting the value inside the input, I'd suggest using .change to trigger the event when the user clicks one of the arrows aswell as when he changes the value directly.

Comment: "Expecting to use a do..whie loop" - you mean a `for` loop?

Comment: Also "javascript:"  label is unnecessary.

Comment: I would prefer a button next to the field.

Comment: naming the input fields `server_name_#` is a bad idea.  You are basically writing array-like data as strings with numeric trailing values.  This will lead to hacky code and [cringe] variable variables.  You should change your `name` attributes to array form... `server_name[1]` -- then accessing these values will be an absolute snap!

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for the tips, I'll try this when I polish my newbie form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with `jQuery`

```js
$('#number').on('change keyup',function(){
  let inputs = '';
  let value = parseInt($(this).val());
  for(let i = 0;i<value;i++){
    inputs += `<input autocomlete="off" type="text" id="server_name${i+1}" name="server_name${i+1}" maxlength="8" tabindex="${i+6+1}" required /></br>` 
  }
  $('#container').html(inputs)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="number">Number of servers</label>
<input type="number" id="number" name="number" min="1" max="32" onkeydown="javascript: return event.keyCode == 69 ? false : true" placeholder="2" required tabindex="6">
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are so many possibilities to achieve this. I guess you dont use any framework or library till yet. So a very plain variant could be the following:

```js
var numberInput = document.getElementById('number');
var serverInputContainer = document.getElementById('container');

numberInput.onchange = function() {
  var inputs = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < parseInt(numberInput.value); ++i) {
    inputs = inputs + '<input type="text" name="server_name_' + i + '"/><br/>';
  }
  serverInputContainer.innerHTML = inputs;
};
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number"/>
<div id="container"></div>
```